# Object assignment in C# not working

Tags: c#, wpf, object, null, variable-assignment

```
CircuitBoard vBoard = this; 
// Find the desired circuit shape
CircuitShape vShape = vBoard.GetComponent(vId);
```

In the above statement the `vBoard` is throwing `null` in certain time. Any idea?

Please help.

Thank you in advance....

more code.. this is a public function

```
class CircuitBoard :Canvas
{
    public void Move(string iBoardId, string iCircuitShapeId, double iXCordinate, double iYCordinate)
        {
          CircuitBoard vBoard = this;

    // secutity check..
          if (null != vBoard)
          {
            string vId = PCBFactory.GetUniqueTag(iCircuitShapeId, vBoard);
            // Find the desired circuit shape
            CircuitShape vShape = vBoard.GetComponent(vId);
            if (vShape != null)
            {
               // do something...
            }
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code snippet, it appears that `this` is null at times.  Can you show more of the code?  What is `this`?

Comment: Where is this code placed? (E.g. inside an instance method of a class?)

Comment: Please clarify! What do you mean by "in certain time"? That sometimes it works, and sometimes does not?

Comment: The two lines of code you've brought seem fine, so we'll need more context. Is this a part of a constructor? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: Ok, after the edit: 1) is this the complete method call, or is there more code after the `this` assignment? 2) Why check `this` for `null` when you can check `vBoard`? 3) Are you sure `this`/`vBoard` is null, or are you getting a `NullReferenceException` which might happen deeper inside?

Comment: yes... i am getting null reference.. so i added a null check.. The call to this function came from diffrent dlls having same instance of CircuitBoard class

Comment: Check out the exception's stack trace - and you sure you're not getting the exception from something happening *inside* the GetComponent call?

Comment: How do you know which line is throwing? Could it be inside `vBoard.GetComponent`?

Comment: Is `PCBFactory.GetUniqueTag` returning null? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: CircuitShape vShape = vBoard.GetComponent(vId); here vBoard is null thrown

Comment: this does not make sense. I cant see why you are getting nullreferenceexception. Since the method or the class is not static you must have called the constructor ahead of calling the method. Therefore, "this" cannot be null. I ask the same thing as all the other in the comments. Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: public static string GetUniqueTag(string iReferenceName, CircuitBoard iCircuitBoard)
    {
      if (null == iCircuitBoard || null == iCircuitBoard.Tag)
      {
        return iReferenceName;
      }
      else
      {
        return (iCircuitBoard.Tag as string) + "." + iReferenceName;
      }

Comment: Try to step into the "GetComponent" method and look for a reason for why it is throwing null.

Comment: in getUnique tag has no chance of modifying the object

Comment: We've stopped looking for ways in which `vBoard` is null. You should check that `GetComponent` *does* get called successfully, but throws a `NullReferenceException` inside it.

Comment: Yes!before calling GetComponent() i am getting exception :(

Comment: what is returned from the "GetUniqueTag"?

Comment: string value  returned

Comment: is the string value null?

Comment: no an expected sting "R1"

Comment: Is it possible that this method is being called through reflection? or wired up to some weak event handler?

Comment: Is this in a Release or Debug build? Optimizations are known to wreak havoc on one's ability to tell exactly which line is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you assigning `this` to something in the first place? Why not just try:

```
class CircuitBoard :Canvas
{
    public void Move(string iBoardId, string iCircuitShapeId, double iXCordinate, double iYCordinate)
    {
        string vId = PCBFactory.GetUniqueTag(iCircuitShapeId, vBoard);
        CircuitShape vShape = this.GetComponent(vId);
        if (vShape != null)
        {
           // do something...
        }
      }
    }
}
```

There's no need to define vBoard at all.

Comment: +1, not because it answers the question (it doesn't, directly) but because it simplifies the code, removing unnecessary elements, and thus will help find the real problem.